# How to create a list of dates using datetime in python?

Tags: python, datetime

Interestingly, I have searched a lot of questions but I cannot find just a simple answer to this question. Or I do find an answer but it won't allow me the flexibility to alter the format of the dates I require.

If I have a specified start and end date like this:

```
start = '2015-08-01' #YYY-MM-DD
end = '2020-07-06'
```

Is there a simple way using `datetime` in python to create a list of dates between these dates that adhere to this format of YYY-MM-DD? And if so, how can I subsequently reverse this list so `list[0]` is equal to today?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using list comprehensions, which is far faster than the loop examples, and doesn't require any external libraries.

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

start = '2015-08-01'
end = '2020-07-06'

start_date = date.fromisoformat(start)
end_date = date.fromisoformat(end)

date_range = [
    # end_date - timedelta(days=i)  # For date objects
    (end_date - timedelta(days=i)).isoformat()  # For ISO-8601 strings
    for i
    in range((end_date - start_date).days)
]
reverse_range = list(reversed(date_range))

print(date_range[0])
print(reverse_range[0])
```

#### Output

```
2020-07-06
2015-08-02
```

Comment: `reverse_range = list(reversed(date_range))` seems to be a bit of a drag, when there's `date_range[::-1]` :)

Comment: would there be a way I can store the elements in the list as datetime objects rather than strings?

Comment: @Johnny Just remove the `.isoformat()` and the parenthesis from the date calculation at the beginning of the list comprehension. [`date.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) returns an ISO-8601 string representation of the datetime object.

Comment: @PrateekDewan Using built-in methods designed specifically for a purpose is almost always better. To the casual observer, your proposed solution is incomprehensible, and you'd have to understand the nuances of Python to understand what's happening there. Using `reversed()` self-documents what is happening.

Comment: Aye aye, Cap'n!

Answer (score 1):

The `datetime.timedelta()` function will help here. Try this:

```
import datetime
dates = []
d = datetime.date(2015,8,1)
while d <= datetime.date(2020,7,6):
    dates.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(d,'%Y-%m-%d'))
    d += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

This will populate the list `dates`, which will look like this:

```
['2015-08-01', '2015-08-02', '2015-08-03', .... , '2020-07-04', '2020-07-05', '2020-07-06']
```

EDIT:

Just use `dates.append(d)` instead of `dates.append(datetime.datetime.strftime(d,'%Y-%m-%d'))` to get a list of `datetime.date` objects instead of `strings`.

Reversing a list is pretty straight-forward in Python:

```
dates = dates[::-1]
```

After the above, `dates[0]` will be `'2020-07-06'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

start = '2015-08-01' #YYY-MM-DD
end = '2020-07-06'

pd.date_range(start, end)

# to start from today

pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp.today(), end)
```

You can also create a range with your desired frequency

```
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='14d') # every 14 dayes
pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H') # hourly and etc
```

Comment: Short and sweet! Just that the question asks for a solution using `datetime`.

Comment: Just as an alternative @PrateekDewan

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
import datetime

def date_range(start, end):
    r = (end+datetime.timedelta(days=1)-start).days
    return [start+datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in range(r)]

start = datetime.date(2015,01,01)
end = datetime.date(2020,07,06)
dateList = date_range(start, end)
print '\n'.join([str(date) for date in dateList])
```